# telebot: вывести из списка названия, чтоб они отправились в одно сообщение

Tags: python, telebot

Код:

```
def check_codes(message):
    projects = ['aa','bb','cc']
    for i in range(len(projects)):
        b = f"id: {i}, {projects[i]}"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'{b}\n*Текст*')
```

Мне нужно чтобы после нумерации все значения которые лежат в списке `projects` выводились в одно сообщение, и переводилось на новую строку. Код сверху только запоминает последнее значение в переменной b и его выводит. Как мне нужно нумеровать все названия, чтоб еще и вывести в одно сообщение?

модуль - `telebot`, версия `python 3.12`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо

```
for i in range(len(projects)):
    b = f"id: {i}, {projects[i]}"
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'{b}\n*Текст*')
```

используйте

```
b = ""
for i, project in enumerate(projects):
    b += f"id: {i}, {project} "
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'{b}\n')
```

---

*Объяснение:*

1. Вместо вывода только последнего значения мы в цикле добавляем всякое значение в начально пустую строку `b`, и таким образом созданную строку выводим на экран.
2. Вместо некрасивого

   ```
   for i in range(len(projects)):
       b = f"id: {i}, {projects[i]}"
   ```

   т.е. избыточного применения индекса `i` для выражения `projects[i]`, я применил итерацию прямо по элементах списка `projects`.
3. Но потому что вы все равно хотите вывести и индекс, я применил к списку `projects` стандартную функцию `enumerate()`, которая из каждого элемента создает пару (индекс, элемент).

Comment: А как сделать чтоб каждое значение `b` с новой строки начиналось? как `end` добавить? Или можно как-то по другому?

Comment: Уже не надо, спасибо все работает =)